# datetime , time python

Tags: python, date, time, gmt

I want to convert a datestring to date in UTC . In addition need to compare this date with current time in UTC and get the difference in milliseconds in python.

I looked at python 
    timedelta
    tzinfo
    time
    date
        datetime

But all of them seem to be confusing , what the best way to solve my problem without using timezone library like pytz(but using only standard python library)

Is there way to convert and compare the date in milliseconds (integer format date) ?

Comment: You should probably use pytz. And it's confusing because dealing with time zones is confusing.

Comment: You should really include an example of the datestring you need to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `datetime` instance and don't provide a time zone (a `tzinfo` object), the resulting `datetime` instance is "timezone-agnostic". It does not care about time zones.

So, if all your dates are in the same time zone, just non't specify the time zone, and you'll be fine.

Use `datetime.utcnow()` to get current time in UTC+0 even if your machine has a different time zone (that `datetime.now()` would respect).

Comment: In the same timezone, and the same season, yes. Otherwise daylight savings may come into play. ;)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: a good note. But I suppose that time _in UTC_ never changes with daylight savings; instead, local time will change relative to UTC time as DLS is engaged and disengaged.

Comment: Exactly. That's why "same timezone" can have different offsets, so even if it is the same timezone you can't replace them with timezone-naive datetimes, if that timezone uses daylight saving. UTC doesn't, though, so it should work for this user, if I interpreted him/her correctly.

Comment: how do i convert and compare the date in milliseconds (integer format date) ?

Comment: @Ashish: for a `datetime` value `d`, I'd use `d.toordinal() * 1000000 + d.microsecond`.

Answer (score 0):

Since both dates are in UTC, you don't need any timezone handling. UTC does not have daylight savings time, and the datetime library can convert UTC times without any external library.

If you were unclear, and the datestring includes a timezone information in a format that doesn't specify offset, then you do have to use pytz or dateutil. But it doesn't seem like it from your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite powerful python extension called `dateutil`. In particular, `dateutil.parser` is really useful for, well, parsing various date/time formats with timezone information available or not.